# Tooltipster stops working after d3.selectAll("").remove();

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3 to generate svg circles that show data with tooltip on click. The data is fetched from an array of objects. I've created a button that removes the circles and then re-generates them from a different array of objects that is a filtered version of the original array of objects.

The circles are created by -

```
    d3.select(idSelector)
    .append("circle")
    .classed("tooltip", true)
    .attr("cx", CordX)
    .attr("cy", CordY)
    .attr("r", 9.21)
```

And then they're removed by -

```
d3.selectAll("circle").remove();
```

everything else seems to be working alright and smoothly i.e. the initial circles get removed, new circles get created but somehow my tooltipster stops working after trying to create the circles again.

The tooltipster is initialized as -

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
      theme: 'tooltipster-punk',
      'maxWidth': 270, // set max width of tooltip box
      contentAsHTML: true, // set title content to html
      trigger: 'custom', // add custom trigger
       triggerOpen: { // open tooltip when element is clicked, tapped (mobile) or hovered
           click: true,
           tap: true,
           mouseenter: false
           },
          triggerClose: { // close tooltip when element is clicked again, tapped or when the mouse leaves it
           click: true,
           scroll: false, // ensuring that scrolling mobile is not tapping!
           tap: true,
           mouseleave: false
           }
  });
```

Tooltipster after edit from comments -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
      theme: 'tooltipster-punk',
      'maxWidth': 270, // set max width of tooltip box
      contentAsHTML: true, // set title content to html
      trigger: 'custom', // add custom trigger
       triggerOpen: { // open tooltip when element is clicked, tapped (mobile) or hovered
           click: true,
           tap: true,
           mouseenter: false
           },
          triggerClose: { // close tooltip when element is clicked again, tapped or when the mouse leaves it
           click: true,
           scroll: false, // ensuring that scrolling mobile is not tapping!
           tap: true,
           mouseleave: false
           }
  });
    $("#legend-button").click(function() {
          $('.tooltipstered').tooltipster("destroy");
          setTimeout(function () {
            $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
      theme: 'tooltipster-punk',
      'maxWidth': 270, // set max width of tooltip box
      contentAsHTML: true, // set title content to html
      trigger: 'custom', // add custom trigger
       triggerOpen: { // open tooltip when element is clicked, tapped (mobile) or hovered
           click: true,
           tap: true,
           mouseenter: false
           },
          triggerClose: { // close tooltip when element is clicked again, tapped or when the mouse leaves it
           click: true,
           scroll: false, // ensuring that scrolling mobile is not tapping!
           tap: true,
           mouseleave: false
           }
  });
        }, 250);
      })
  });
```

Any idea why that might be happening? And how I can get it to work?

Thank you!

Comment: how are the circles re-created after removal?

Comment: @GrafiCode With the same code above, just using a different array of objects, rest everything else remains the same

Comment: is tooltipster initialized only by applying the class `tooltip` on some element, or does it require a javascript initialization too?

Comment: @GrafiCode the class tooltip is only to show the cursor as a pointer. I've added the initialization to the post above! Thank you!

Comment: ok, I think you have to destroy and then re-initialize tooltipster every time you remove and recreate the circles. this answer seems to be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39498055/5334486

Comment: @GrafiCode it's working now! Thank you!!